# variables not holding data in ionic angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous, ionic-framework

I am very confused as to why the variables is not holding.
I have a variable **user** which is assigned with the data in **userData()**. But it's undefined when console log within the constructor and *ProfilePage*.

[image]

**share-service.ts**

```
export class ShareService {
  uid: string;
  user;

  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.uid = currentUser.uid;
    this.userData();
    console.log('[constructor]user: ', this.user);
  }

  userData() {
    this.db.object(`users/${this.uid}`).snapshotChanges().subscribe(data => {
      this.user = data.payload.val();
      console.log('[userData]user: ', this.user);
    });
  }

  getUser() {
    return this.user;
  }

}
```

**profile.ts**

```
export class ProfilePage {
  user;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseService: FirebaseService, shareService: ShareService) {
    console.log('[profile.ts]', shareService.getUser());
  }

}
```

- "angularfire2": "5.0.0-rc.4",
- "firebase": "4.8.2",
- "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
- "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
- "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
- "typescript": "2.4.2"

I have already tried searching for similar questions like for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36844287/angular-2-variable-is-not-updating-inside-service/36844450) and read that it has something to do with how angular is **asynchronous** and then upon further investigation I read that **promise** is needed like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37719306/whats-the-equivalent-of-angulars-q-in-angular2). I also read somewhere that **.then()** should be used.

I tried several ways to implement those into this use case scenario but all turned out with syntax errors.

In need of advice, please.

Comment: I dont know what you want to do, but you have an observable there, not a promise. What is your question?

Comment: @AlanGrosz I have a variable **user** which is assigned with the data in **userData()**. But it's undefined when console log within the constructor

Comment: where exactly you want to access `this.user`? in the constructor?

Comment: @SurajRao accessing on other page by importing  
`import {ShareService } from '../../providers/share-service/share-service'` and then getting by calling `shareService.getUser();`

Comment: check my answer.. call `getUser().then(data=> //in here)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular provides [Async Pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe) for this type of Async methods.

> user information will be come from firebase server, and it will take time.
>  in the meanwhile, javascript continues its execution.

that's why you got `this.user` as `undefined`, because when JS execute that line, data is not come from server and not assign to it.

so we need to handle this type of methods either by

- **callback** -- [callback to promises](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/javascript-from-callbacks-to-async-await-1cc090ddad99)
- [**promises**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise)
- [**async-await**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)
- **(here in angular case) [observables](http://reactivex.io/documentation/observable.html)**

so 
try this

**share-service.ts**

```
export class ShareService {
 uid: string;

 constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
 let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
 this.uid = currentUser.uid;
 }

 getUser() {
   return this.db.object(`users/${this.uid}`)
     .snapshotChanges()
     .map(data => data.payload.val());
 }
}
```

**profile.ts**

```
export class ProfilePage {
 user;

 constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public firebaseService: 
  FirebaseService, shareService: ShareService) {
  this.user = shareService.getUser();
 }
}
```

**In Template**

```
<div *ngIf="user | async as _user; else loadingUsers">
  {{_user.username}}
</div>
<ng-template #loadingUsers>
  Loading...
</ng-template>
```

Comment: It's simple and it works. But what if I need to use `this.user.some_property` to do some logic inside code?

Comment: for example, in template 
    `<div (click)="editUser(user)">edit</div>`
or
     `this.user = shareService.getUser().map(user => this.data = user);`

Comment: this [blog post](https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-async-data-binding-with-ng-if-and-ng-else) will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you read it..

```
 userData() {
    return this.db.object(`users/${this.uid}`).snapshotChanges()
    .pipe(map(data => {

      this.user = data.payload.val();
      return this.user;
      console.log('[userData]user: ', this.user);
    }));//import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
```

}

If you want to access it anywhere use `subscribe()` on `getUser()`.

```
  getUser(){
    if(!this.user){
        return this.userData();//return the db call if not set
    }else{
    return of(this.user);//import {of} from 'rxjs/Observable/of;'
  }
```

In constructor,

```
  constructor(public db: AngularFireDatabase) {
    let currentUser = firebase.auth().currentUser;
    this.uid = currentUser.uid;
    this.getUser().subscribe(u=>{
        console.log('[constructor]user: ', u);
    });//subscribe to the observable.
  }
```

Comment: It's not working, console.log not even getting called.
How do i do it with async/await instead?

Comment: what do you mean not getting called? any console errors?

Comment: no error at all.. console.log inside **.then** is not executed.

Comment: sorry. my bad.. it is `return Promise.resolve(this.user);`

Comment: Still the same..
`userData() { return this.db.object(`users/${this.uid}`).snapshotChanges().toPromise().then(data =>  this.user = data.payload.val(); console.log('[userData]user: ', data.payload.val()); return this.user; })}` console.log inside userData() i also not being executed.

Comment: you are missing a return somewhere

Comment: sorry accidentally submitted my comment earlier without completing what i was going to type. can you read my previous comment again.

Comment: then its something to do with db call... otherwise try chaining observables

Comment: i was able to get the correct data within userData() in the initial code.

Comment: ok... then ytou need to chain observables.. `toPromise()` is not working with angularfire2 for some reason.. what is your rxjs version?

Comment: "rxjs": "^5.5.6"

Comment: Typescript error `The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'Observable<{}>'.` at `userData()`

Comment: did you specify a return type for the function?

Comment: I did as you instructed. [this is my code](https://github.com/tanjunior/ionic3app)

Comment: more details of the typescript error [https://github.com/tanjunior/ionic3app/issues/1](https://github.com/tanjunior/ionic3app/issues/1)

Comment: ok.. got it... change import of map to `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';` to use pipeable operator. and also you are missing a return in that function. More [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/pipeable-operators.md)

Comment: `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map'; you forgot an `s`

Comment: Oh you are right, didn't see the **s** behind. no more error now, but doesn't solve the asynchronous issue. kinda back to square one?
[https://github.com/tanjunior/ionic3app/issues/2](https://github.com/tanjunior/ionic3app/issues/2)

Comment: you cant console log _outside subscribe_.. do it inside.read up on rxjs and asynchronous programming

Comment: i did a console log to test, because {{ user.username }} is not showing up on my view.

Comment: view may load before you receive data in  class variable.. put as `{{user?.username}}`